# How can I add an image to an ical event in code?

Tags: php, icalendar

I am using [qcal](http://code.google.com/p/qcal/) to generate an ics file from PHP. I would like to attach an image which should appear in the description when an Outlook user clicks on the link. This is the ical event being generated.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT 
UID:600e6a4b882c446ed224791103919596
CLASS:private 
DTSTART:20120330T000000 
DTEND:20120331T000000 
DESCRIPTION:100m Final 
SUMMARY: Some text. 
PRIORITY:1 
ATTACH:FMTTYPE=image/jpeg:http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/A_tiger_in_Pilibhit_Tiger_Reserve.jpg/220px-A_tiger_in_Pilibhit_Tiger_Reserve.jpg 
END:VEVENT
```

The attachment is not showing up in Outlook. Can anyone confirm if this should be possible?

Answer (score 0):

with outlook 2007 it looks like you have to remove the fmttype property but you still have to deal with outlook security settings to display  the attachment.

ATTACH:http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/A_tiger_in_Pilibhit_Tiger_Reserve.jpg/220px-A_tiger_in_Pilibhit_Tiger_Reserve.jpg

you might also want to fold the line and change the CLASS:private to CLASS:PRIVATE for further compliance.

Comment: While this will make the appointment in Outlook appear to have an attachment, it isn't clearly visible in the message body or noticeably available for download (using Outlook 2013).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an ancient question, but the proposed answer doesn't work. What Outlook (Office 365) produces when making an .ical event with an image attached is this:

```
ATTACH;ENCODING=BASE64;VALUE=BINARY;X-FILENAME=some_file.png:the_base64_encoded_content_of_the_file
```

The base64 encoded content of the file is cut into separate lines of 74 characters with a preceding tab (character).

Note: I'm not sure if all other programs support this format, but anyway. ;)